# How to add new data to useInfiniteQuery in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am getting started with React Query and using useInfiniteQuery hook for infinite scrolling but I want to implement new feature is **add new post** (new element) which the new element will be add to the start of the array `data` in useInfiniteQuery.

My example code:

```
  const { status, data, error, isFetching, isFetchingNextPage, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage } = useInfiniteQuery(
        ['posts'],
        async ({ pageParam = '' }) => {
            const res = await postAPI.getPost(as, pageParam, PAGE_LIMIT);
            return res;
        },
        {
            getNextPageParam: (lastPage) =>
                lastPage.length && lastPage.length >= 5 ? lastPage[lastPage.length - 1]?.id : undefined,
        },
    );

   ...
   <button onClick={() => data.unshift(...)}>Add new data</button> // this idea of ​​mine doesn't seem to work
```

Can I use `queryClient.setQueryData(queryKey, newData)` for this?

Comment: Typically you wouldn't/shouldn't add things to the cache when you perform mutations. You should invalidate your cache when you perform mutations. Then the query will update itself with the new information from the backend which should include the mutation.

Comment: @ChadS. How can I invalidate cache?

Comment: In the mutation hooks `onSuccess` handler you would call `queryClient.invalidateQueries(['posts'])` since `['posts']` is the query key used by this infinite query, it will cause the query to re-fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```js
const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (body) => addPost(body),
    onSuccess: (newPost) => {
        queryClient.setQueryData(['posts'], (oldData) => ({
            pages: [[newPost],...oldData.pages],
            pageParams: [...oldData.pageParams, { cursor: newPost.id }],
        }))
    },
})
```

```html
<button onClick={() => mutation.mutate(body)}>
```